# Coded UI - UITestControlCollection using FindMatchingControls() is empty on consecutive runs

Tags: c#, wpf, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, specflow

I use **SpecFlow** with **Coded UI** to create some automated functional tests for a **WPF** application.

Let's see the following SpecFlow scenario:

```
Scenario: Issue
When Results button is pressed
    When Result 123 is selected
When Results button is pressed
    When Result 123 is selected
```

1st and 3rd row parameter: *Results*
2nd and 4th row parameter: *123*

Here are the methods for the upper mentioned steps:

**When Results button is pressed**

```
public void PressButton(string buttonName)
{
    WpfButton uIButton = this.UIAUT.UIButton;
    uIButton.SearchProperties[WpfButton.PropertyNames.Name] = buttonName;

    uIButton.WaitForControlEnabled();
    Mouse.Click(uIButton);
}
```

**When Result 123 is selected**

```
public void SelectResultByID(string resultId)
{
    WpfListItem uIResult = this.UIAUT.UITier1List.UITier2ListBox.UITier3ListItem;
    var allResults = uIResult.FindMatchingControls();

    foreach (WpfListItem item in allResults)
    {
        string[] elem = item.GetChildren().GetNamesOfControls();
        if (elem[0] == resultID)
        {
            Mouse.Click(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The first three rows are OK. When the 4th step `When Result 123 is selected` is executed again `var allResults = uIResult.FindMatchingControls();` is empty so the `foreach` part is skipped, no action is taken and the test is passed.

Could someone tell me what is wrong? It is obvious that I miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you code is generated by recording (or is similar) then I would suspect the "cacheing" nature of the higher level UI Controls. The application may draw one UI Control containing the first `123` and draw another UI Control for the second `123`. These controls look identical but are different and have different window-ids (or handles or whatever). One of the UI Controls in

```
WpfListItem uIResult = this.UIAUT.UITier1List.UITier2ListBox.UITier3ListItem;
```

probably refers to the UI Control of the first `123` even though it is no longer on display. I suspect `UITier3ListItem` or its child controls; if it were `...1...` or `...2...` then I would expect a failure message rather than zero matches.

Comment: Thanks AdrianHHH! _These controls look identical but are different and have different window-ids (or handles or whatever)._ - I suspected the same thing and it was proved during debugging the code. You answered my _ill-asked question_. Could you offer a solution or a hint to workaround the presented issue? In other words, in step 4 I would like to click on the same control.

Comment: @Leeway I think you need to re-evaluate the higher level controls. Try calling `this.UIAUT.UITier1List.Find()`. That should also clear the lower controls causing them to be re-evaluated when needed. If that works then, for performance reasons, consider calling `this.UIAUT.UITier1List.UITier2ListBox.Find()` or even `this.UIAUT.UITier1List.UITier2ListBox.UITier3ListItem.Find()` instead.