# CodedUI WPF Test: Cannot perform 'Click' on the hidden control

Tags: wpf, coded-ui-tests, visual-studio-2015

I've set-up a relatively basic Coded UI test for a WPF application.  The test opens an application, presses a few buttons and then closes it.  Here's the test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethod1()
{                
    ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"c:\myapp\bin\Debug\myapp.exe");

    this.UIMap.LoginAndClickDoAction1();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        this.UIMap.DoAction1();
    }

    this.UIMap.ExitMyApp();
}
```

The application launches fine, logs in and clicks the buttons the first time.  It subsequently throws the exception:

```
Cannot perform 'Click' on the hidden control
```

When it throws this seems to vary, but the button that it gives is never hidden.  After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893968/cannot-perform-click-on-the-hidden-control), I tried inserting:

```
uIMyButton1.Find();
uIMyButton2.Find();
```

Into the UIMap at the top of the test, but it made no difference.

What could be causing this error and how would I go about debugging it?

Quick disclaimer: this question relates to VS2015, so I suppose it could be a legitimate MS bug.

Answer (score 0):

Details of `uIMyButton1` and `uIMyButton2` are not shown in the question. They may be used in code of this style (once intervening declarations are combined):

```
UIControl aControl = this.UIMap.uione.uitwo.uithree.uIMyButton1.Click();
```

Any of the parent properties of the buttons may be for the item that has been redisplayed. So I think the question linked in this question shows the answer, just that the `Find()` should be applied at a higher level.

You would try calling:

```
uithree.Find();
```

if that is not successful then call

```
uitwo.Find();
```

and so on.

For performance reasons `Find` is called as deep into the hierarchy as possible.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter where I call this, I get the same problem.  I've also tried checking whether the control exists and if not then waiting.  I've got it to the stage now where it consistently goes round the loop once and then crashes